# Gorgonopsid--What's In a Name?

Tags: terminology, taxonomy, etymology

[image]

The Gorgon--a terrifying, monstrous female with hairs made of live snakes and a stare so horrifying that it would literally turn you to stone.

[image]

The Gorgonopsid--a predatory protomammal that hunted down its prey via saber-like teeth.

Herein lies the problem.  The gorgonopsid looks nothing even remotely like a snake, nor is it likely that it could stare down its own prey into a statue.  So why call this family of predatory protomammals "gorgonopsids", anyway?

Comment: If I had to guess, it is because the skull of this animal must have horrified early paleontologist of the 1890s. This was an animal that had a skull that was both reptilian and mammalian. Some kind of horrid in between animal. Neither mammal nor reptile. In the era before the evolution theory was accepted...this animal looked like a defiance to the order of God's creations. There were fish, amphibians, reptiles, birds and mammals. The five kingdoms of animal life. There should not be such a beast, a half reptile, half mammal. Like the gorgon half beast, half human.

Comment: Gorgon (via Latin from Greek Gorgō, from gorgos meaning **‘terrible'**) + opsid (Ancient Greek ὄψις (ópsis) for "appearance”) (often referring to the face).